# Why would IntelliJ IDEA not recognize standard functions and $s?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, apache-spark-sql

I use Spark 2.3.0.

The following code fragment works fine in `spark-shell`:

```
def transform(df: DataFrame): DataFrame =  {
  df.select(
    explode($"person").alias("p"),
    $"history".alias("h"),
    $"company_id".alias("id")
  )
```

Yet when editing within Intellij, it will not recognize the `select`, `explode` and `$` functions. These are my dependencies within SBT:

```
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies ++= {
  val sparkVer = "2.1.0"
  Seq(
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVer % "provided" withSources(),
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVer % "provided" withSources()
  )
}
```

Is there anything missing? An import statement, or an additional library?

Comment: remove `% "provided" withSources()` from both dependencies and you should be fine. with those options sbt didn't download them and assumed that  you have provided them manually

Comment: Tried this. Still Intellij marks those functions red, and will not navigate to them. It can find the class ```DataFrame``` though, and navigation to the ```select``` function from there works. Upvoting your comment anyway, since ```provided``` does not make sense here.

Comment: clean your project, synchronize and package again. should work then

Comment: What are your imports ? Are you import `o.a.s.sql.functions._` and `spark.implicits._`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the following import in the `transform` method (to have `explode` available):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
```

You could also do the following to be precise on what you import.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.explode
```

It works in `spark-shell` since it does the import by default (so you don't have to worry about such simple things :)).

```
scala> spark.version
res0: String = 2.3.0

scala> :imports
 1) import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._ (69 terms, 1 are implicit)
 2) import spark.implicits._       (1 types, 67 terms, 37 are implicit)
 3) import spark.sql               (1 terms)
 4) import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._ (354 terms)
```

As to `$` it is also imported by default in `spark-shell` for your convenience. Add the following to have it in your method.

```
import spark.implicits._
```

Depending on where you have `transform` method defined you may add an implicit parameter to the `transform` method as follows (and skip adding the `import` above):

```
def transform(df: DataFrame)(implicit spark: SparkSession): DataFrame =  {
  ...
}
```

I'd however prefer using the `SparkSession` bound to the input DataFrame (which seems cleaner and...geeker :)).

```
def transform(df: DataFrame): DataFrame =  {
  import df.sparkSession.implicits._
  ...
}
```

---

As a bonus, I'd also cleanup your `build.sbt` so it would look as follows:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % 2.1.0" % "provided" withSources()
```

You won't be using artifacts from `spark-core` in your Spark SQL applications (and it's a transitive dependency of `spark-sql`).

Answer (score 0):

Intellij does not have spark.implicits._ library available, therefore explode throws an error. Do remember to create the SparkSession.builder() object before importing.

Apply the following code, this works:

```
 val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .master("local")
      .appName("ReadDataFromTextFile")
      .getOrCreate()

    import spark.implicits._

    val jsonFile = spark.read.option("multiLine", true).json("d:/jsons/rules_dimensions_v1.json")
    jsonFile.printSchema()

    //jsonFile.select("tag").select("name").show()
    jsonFile.show()

    val flattened = jsonFile.withColumn("tag", explode($"tag"))
    flattened.show()
```